# Spring 3.1 Controller not accepting ajax post

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am creating an AJAX form using spring 3.1 MVC. I am confused and have searched the internet and stackoverflow for a solution to my problem but have been unsuccessful so far. I am Also using Tiles 2.2.2

I am getting a WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported

The Controller methods

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/createProject", method=RequestMethod.POST,headers ="Accept:*/*")
         public @ResponseBody Project createProject(@RequestBody Project project){
               try {
                  projectBusiness.createProject(project);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
          return project;
        }
   @RequestMapping(value="/createProject", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView displayCreateProjectForm(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("createProject");
        mav.addObject("project", new Project());
        return mav;
    }
```

My JSP

```
   $(function() {

    var url = $('#myForm').attr('action'); //http://localhost:7001/ProjectPortfolioTracker/app/projects/createProject
    $('#submitForm').click(function(e){
        console.log("hello");
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $('#myForm').serialize();
        alert(formData);

        console.log('in form click');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data:formData,
            success: function(){
               alert('success');
            },error: function(){
                alert('failure');
            },
        }).done(function() {
        alert("ajax post completed"); 
    });

    });
});
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Create a Project</h1>
    <table>
        <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/projects/createProject" id="myForm">
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td><td><textarea id="description" name="description" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Category:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category">
                        <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
                        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
                        <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estimated Duration:(in days)</td><td><input id="durationSlider" type="range" min="1" max="90" step="1" value="1"/></td><td><input type="text" id="durationValue" name="estimatedduration" readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estimated Cost:(in 100's of dollars)</td><td><input id="costSlider" type="range" min="1" max="500" step="1" value="1" /></td><td><input type="text" id="costValue" name="estimatedcost"readonly/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Objective:</td><td><textarea id="objective" name="objective"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Resources:</td><td><input id="resources" type="number" value="0" name="resources"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="status">
                        <option value="design">Design Stage</option>
                        <option value="working">Work in Progress</option>
                        <option value="finished">Finished</option>
                        <option value="publishing">Publishing</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Supports:</td><td><textarea id="supports" name="supports"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ManagerID</td><td><input type="number" value="0" id="managerid" name="managerid"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit" id="submitForm">Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
```

I Should also mention I got the actual information to post through the ajax but I was not handling the controller code in an ajax way meaning i was still returing a view at the end of the method, since the change to using @ResponseBody and @RequestBody is when the problem started to happen

Forgive my horrible formatting I am still learning.

Comment: Do you see anything in the log files when the app starts up that mentions not being able to create an endpoint for POST?

Comment: No but I think its set up due to the following INFO: Mapped "{[/app/projects/createProject],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[Accept:*/*],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public model.Project controller.ProjectController.createProject(model.Project)

Comment: My advice would be to debug through the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter class (specifically the "handle" method) and see what's going on.

Comment: seeing how you have GET and POST mapped to /createProject (i'm assuming at `/ProjectPortfolioTracker/app/projects/createProject`), can you get to GET version OK? If so then I'd debug at the client end during the POST to make sure it's hitting the correct url.

Comment: The GET version is working fine, as far as i can tell the ajax call is being posted to the same url i added a console.log to the url variable and its as it should be /ProjectPortfolioTracker/app/projects/createProject

Comment: El Guapo I am having some trouble using the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter do you have a site which could help me understand how to implement this test?

Comment: Also am using tiles 2.2.2 forgot to mention that above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So The issue was the Headers paramenter of the @RequestMapping it didn't like the Accept:*/* which I assumed to be to accepting anything when i changed it to Accept:"application/json" it started to work properly Thanks to all who commented trying to help